# How to set for for NumericTextBox dynamically in Asp.Net MVC Kendo?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

how to set NumericTextBox format dynamically like below. I tried this but it's not working.

```
var dynamicValue = "###,###.000";

@(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBox<double>()
    .Name("Amount")
    .Spinners(false).Format("dynamicValue")
    .Decimals(3)
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%; height: 27px;", tabindex = "6" })
    .Events(e => e.Change("OnAmountChange"))
)
```

dynamicValue is set as the response of GET API call.

Comment: I think you will need to set it with javascript whenever it needs to be changed.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown how and what to set?

Comment: Well, as i said, using javascript. Probably using [`setOptions`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/widget/methods/setoptions) method as you need to change an initial option of the widget